# How to parse the SubReddits JSON using Codable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, codable

The URL I used was "https://www.reddit.com/subreddits/.json" which will give you the JSON format of Reddit's Subreddits.

My Codable Struct Models are as follows:

```
struct SubredditsData: Codable {
    let data: SubredditData
}

struct SubredditData: Codable {
    let children: [Children]
}

struct Children: Codable {
    let data: ChildrenData
}

struct ChildrenData: Codable {
    let title: String
    let icon_img: String
    let display_name_prefixed: String
    let name: String
}
```

and of course the Model for the Subreddit

```
struct SubredditsModel {
    let title: String
    let display_name_prefixed: String
    let name: String
}
```

I then performed a request and the actual parsing itself

```
func parseSubRedditsJSON(_ subredditsRawData: Data) -> [SubredditsModel]? {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        var subReddits = [SubredditsModel]()
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(SubredditsData.self, from: subredditsRawData)
        let data = decodedData.data
        let children = data.children
        for item in children {
            let childrenData = item.data
            let title = childrenData.title
            let display_name_prefixed = childrenData.display_name_prefixed
            let name = childrenData.name
            let subReddit = SubredditsModel(title: title, display_name_prefixed: display_name_prefixed, name: name)
            subReddits.append(subReddit)
        }
        return subReddits
    } catch {
        subredditsDelegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
        return nil
    }
}//end of parseSubRedditsJSON
```

I'm returning the data to the view controller from the request manager via protocol delegate which works fine. The problem is I'm getting an error on this line

```
let decodedData = try decoder.decode(SubredditsData.self, from: subredditsRawData)
```

The error says:

```
valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), 
CodingKeys(stringValue: "children", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 5", intValue: 5), 
CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), 
CodingKeys(stringValue: "icon_img", intValue: nil)], 
debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

I must be missing something, or haven't implemented the correct way of parsing using Swift codable.

Comment: The error says it all if you read it carefully, `icon_img` can be null and must be declared optional, `let icon_img: String?` (Or you can simply remove it if you are not using it)

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have noticed that. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of some of the fields are not optional, it may require string type or null, making it optional will solve this problem.

```
struct SubredditsData: Codable {
    let data: SubredditData
 }

 struct SubredditData: Codable {
    let children: [Children]
 }

 struct Children: Codable {
   let data: ChildrenData
 }

 struct ChildrenData: Codable {
   let title: String?
   let icon_img: String?
   let display_name_prefixed: String?
   let name: String?
 }
```

Comment: Why are you making all fields optional?